# ASP.NET MVC remove foreign key constraint via fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ....

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser UserCreated { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser UserModified { get; set; }
}
```

The `UserCreated` at the moment I have configured with foreign key relation to the `User` table. This is something I don't want.

My DbMigration script should not create the foreign key relationship between these, since I should be able to delete a user, without having to actually delete all records in the menus before I can do that.

Is this possible to avoid and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use your navigation properties of `UserCreated` and `UserModified` EF Migrations needs that foriegn key to know how to retrieve that data.

If I were you, I would remove those two navigation properties and make an Extension method you can use to grab the `UserCreated` and `UserModified`.  Your code will look similar to the following.

```cs
public static class MenuItemExtensions {
  public static ApplicationUser GetUserCreated(this MenuItem menuItem, DbContext db) {
    db.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == menuItem.CreatedBy);
  }

  public static ApplicationUser GetUserModified(this MenuItem menuItem, DbContext db) {
    db.ApplicationUsers.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == menuItem.ModifiedBy );
  }
}
```

I'm assuming `Username` is the name that the `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy` correspond to.

**Also**, remember to add in DB indices for these columns so this join isn't *super* slow!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the input. I am very new to this though, and havent played alot with extension methods.

I have created your suggested extension, but how would I retrive this data in my controller, so I have it in my ViewModel. 

I cant seem to find the method GetUserCreated anywhere.

Hope the question isnt to stupid:S

Comment: Say the variable name of your MenuItem is menuItem. You would just use var username = menuItem.GetUserCreated(db). You will need to stick a using XX; at the top of the file to point to the namespace your extension is located within.

Comment: Haha, I tried that, but my namespace was wrong, doohhh:>:(

Comment: One thing to note if you are going to always return usercreated/usermodified when retrieving MenuItem, you will probably want to perform one query to get all of the information. Currently with my suggestion, you'll need to query 3 times. Once for the MenuItem. Once for the CreatedBy. Once for the ModifiedBy. You'll want to write a query that returns a MenuItem, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy all in one complex LINQ statement.

Comment: Yah. At the moment I have the extensions if I need to invoke them. The extra calls in this case would be ok. I already made some of the linq statement if I decide I go that what somewhere else. TY for your help.